# ERROR: unable to download video

Tags: youtube-dl

I have been using `youtube-dl` to download videos from YouTube, but suddenly it stopped working:

```
youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wglrcytdE9Y&feature=related"

[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] wglrcytdE9Y: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] wglrcytdE9Y: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] wglrcytdE9Y: Extracting video information

ERROR: unable to download video

youtube-dl --version
2012.02.27
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm getting this with every video, even videos that have previously worked. The URL that `youtube-dl` attempts to download from is returning a 403 error, so I suspect Youtube changed something internally that broke the script (not for the first time).

There's been quite a bit of youtube-dl development activity [today](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/graphs/commit-activity), and the latest version in [github](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) works, so you should probably pull that. `youtube-dl` can do this automatically with the `-U` flag:

```
$ youtube-dl -U
Updating to latest version...
Updated youtube-dl. Restart youtube-dl to use the new version.
```

Comment: Works! Didn't know about the `-U` flag - is that the same as upgrading with aptitude? (I use `sid`.)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg No, it downloads the latest version from github directly. Most likely the version in your package manager is still too old

Answer (score 3):

Check [this fix](https://github.com/virtulis/youtube-dl/commit/9ca667065e7371322e0970421fb4e03f8bd00b9e):

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git
sudo apt-get install zip
nano youtube_dl/InfoExtractors.py (modify line 405)
make compile
./youtube-dl
```

Answer (score -4):

A common mistake is not escaping the `&`. Putting the URL in quotes should solve this problem:

```
$ youtube-dl -t "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHlDtZ6Oc3s&feature=channel_video_title"
```

Comment: Its quoted in OP's question.

Comment: Besides it already being correct in the question, this mistake wouldn't cause the error he got